# How to encode hexadecimal color in NSRGB tag of xml file of xib?

Tags: iphone, ios, xib, nib

My task is to create xib file dynamically with all its parameter such as background color.
I am creating xib file by creating xml content and then writing xib file.
I am only able to encode its specific color e.g. for black color NSRGB tags are -

```
<object class="NSColor" key="IBUITextColor" id="1026485712">
    <int key="NSColorSpace">1</int>
    <bytes key="NSRGB">MCAwIDAAA</bytes>
</object>
```

For red color -

```
<object class="NSColor" key="IBUITextColor">
    <int key="NSColorSpace">2</int>
    <bytes key="NSRGB">MC45MzcyNTQ5NjUzIDAgMC4yMDM5MjE1ODYzAA</bytes>
</object>
```

I don't know how to convert other hexadecimal color code (#0000CD) to this encoded color 
of NSRGB (MC45MzcyNTQ5NjUzIDAgMC4yMDM5MjE1ODYzAA). I am not able to know the criteria to encode the hexadecimal color for NSRGB color code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm betting the "red" you listed is (239,0,52) or #EF0035. If I'm right, I think I've got this figured out...

I'm using .NET to do this, but I think you could figure it out in Objective-C.

You'll want to do this:

Convert your hexadecimal values to decimal values:

`#0000CD --> (0,0,205)`

Divide each decimal value by 255 and keep up to 10 digits:

`(0,0,205) --> (0,0,0.8039215686)`

Turn these values into a string, with each value separated by a space (no space at end):

`0 0 0.8039215686`

Convert this into a byte array:

`48 32 48 32 48 46 56 48 51 57 50 49 53 54 56 54`

Add a "zero" byte `0` to the end:

`48 32 48 32 48 46 56 48 51 57 50 49 53 54 56 54 0`

Now, just convert this to a base64 string. My results for `#0000CD` are:

`MCAwIDAuODAzOTIxNTY4NgA=`

I think the `=` at the end is just a place-holder, but this isn't my area of expertise.

***Note:*** There is an extra `A` at the end of the first value ("MCAwIDAAA") that I haven't figured out; are you sure that's 3 A's and not 2?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is:
you should just decode the base64 bytes "MCAwIDAAA"
e.g:

red 
MSAwIDAAA ----base64 decode---> 1 0 0

orange
MSAwLjUgMAA ----base64 decode---> 1 0.5 0

you catch the color RGB value!